# Can anyone identify what sort of egg or pupa this is?

Tags: insects, figs

[image]Can anyone identify what these little critters might be?  We are
Trying to be on the offense for the fig beetles that are sure to return this season and so we began inspecting the tree and the dirt.

This is not likely related to fig beetles as they are not prone to laying eggs on leaves unless they’re on the ground.  Does anyone here know what this might be?